# Distribution of Bernoulli random variable conditional on noisy measure of "p"

Tags: probability

Suppose that $r$ is normally distributed, 
$$r\sim N(\bar{r},\sigma_r),$$
and $x$ conditional on $r$ is normally distributed with mean $r$
$$x|r\sim N(r,\sigma_x).$$
I am interested in a random variable $y$ that follows a Bernoulli distribution condition on $p$
$$y|p \sim \text{Bernoulli}(p),$$
where 
$$p=Prob(r>0).$$
How can I find the distribution of $y$ conditional on $x$? If I do not know $p$, but only a noisy measure of $p$, what is the distribution of $y$?

Comment: I'm sorry. It should say that $$r\sim N(\bar{r},\sigma_r)$$ and $$p=\text{Prob}(r<0)$$ And $$x|r\sim N(r,\sigma_x)$$

Comment: Make an edit to correct your question.